# Rails - relative paths - techniques

Tags: javascript, css, ruby

I am struggling to understand the intricacies of how to address various assets in rails. Having had some help sorting out a related question I wanted to expand a little further.

In my application I have imported a website template (a limited part at present) from wrap bootstrap. I am trying to get this to work and I have been hitting issues with references to images etc that are in none standard folders.

In the wrap bootstrap theme the *JavaScript* assets are in a folder called *js*, css assets are in folder called *css* and images are in a folder called *img*. Each of these folders have multiple subfolders.

The individual js, css files reference a whole host of paths for different reasons and often these references are failing. I firstly tried to copy all of the assets into the standard rails folders (*assets/javascripts etc*) but this failed as many of the files imported will reference the *js* folder. I don't want to move the imported files around for the same reason. My approach therefore has been to try and identify the issues in the imported files and fix the path references.

I have already had assistance with addressing one of the issues in a  block but I have other issues within js and css files. I am also aware that the way relative paths are addressed in development can fail in production when the assets are compiled into the *public/asset*s folder.

I was hoping therefore to get best practice advice on the basis of the 2 issues I know I still need to address.

The first is addressing an image path within a block of *JavaScript* code as per below:-

```
        var setColor = function (color, data_header) {
            jQuery('#style_color').attr("href", "../assets/css/theme-colors/" + color + ".css");
            if(data_header == 'light'){
                jQuery('.logo img').attr("src", "../assets/img/themes/logo1-" + color + ".png");
                jQuery('#logo-footer').attr("src", "../assets/img/themes/logo2-" + color + ".png");
                jQuery('.navbar-brand img').attr("src", "../assets/img/themes/logo1-" + color + ".png");
            } else if(data_header == 'dark'){
                jQuery('.logo img').attr("src", "../assets/img/themes/logo1-" + color + ".png");
                jQuery('#logo-footer').attr("src", "../assets/img/themes/logo2-" + color + ".png");
            }
        }
```

This function is located in *assets/js/plugins* and is called from a script block located in an html.erb file in *assets/views/open_pages*. The relative path looks correct but the image doesn't appear, I get an error in the browser console window and in the rails server window I get a routing error. I can't understand how I am meant to reference this relative path in *JavaScript* as it looks correct to me.

The second issue is similar but in a css file. The snippet below should reference the correct path but again this fails. I also read somewhere that this type of notation can fail in production

```
/*Dotted Map*/
.footer-v1 .footer .map-img {
   background: url(../img/map-img.png) 5px 60px no-repeat;
}
```

Could anyone outline how these types of issues should be approached? I am obviously missing something critical in my understanding and it is really impeding progress.

Thanks for your time.

D

Comment: I'm currently going through the same issues trying to integrate a wrapbootstrap them into my rails project.  I've made some progress but still have a ways to go.  I found several tutorials online (some with conflicting info) but found [this one](http://www.notch8.com/implementing-a-bootstrap-theme/) to be helpful .

Comment: Thanks. I found when moving js, css and image files into the standard rails asset folders all sort of things were failing as in some of the files they reference the highest level folders (e.g. img folder or js folder). I concluded this was going to be too big an overhead but I may have been wrong.

Comment: Second one would be `background: url(image_path('map-img.png')) 5px 60px no-repeat;`

Comment: If this is giving you endless problems, there is nothing stopping you from just dumping all your assets in the `public` folder, bypassing the assets pipeline, and reference them like in any normal framework.

Comment: @Iceman for the second part of this question your suggestion works, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This can be a real headache in Rails, trying to work with the assets pipeline. Since at the server you don't have access to the `color` variable, you have to do something like this. There might be a smarter solution, but I'm not seeing it at the moment at least.

```
var link = '';
if (color == 'red') {
  link = "<%= asset_path('theme-colors/red.css') %>";
}
if (color == 'blue') {
  link = "<%= asset_path('theme-colors/blue.css') %>";
}

jQuery('#style_color').attr("href", link);
```

And, as with the earlier answer, you have to add this to `config/initializers/assets.rb`.

```
Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('assets', 'css')
```

This should move you a bit in the right direction at least. And also have a look at the [guides on the assets pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html).